# Swift UITextField & Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, performance

I have experienced problems with Run-time. When launching Simulation, as soon as I attempt to type in Email "UITextField", the application crashes and displaying the general sigabrt Main thread issue (12).

I have checked the Storyboard outlets, references and all redundant connections - all in-order.

**Please guide and suggest advice with main Build, Capabilities, and launch settings**?
It seems when I tried to execute with iPhone launch, a spiral happened.

Here is my main UI Swift code for Sign-in component Application:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signInToTabBar", sender: nil)
    }    
}

func handleTextField() {
    passwordTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SignUpViewController.textFieldDidChange), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    emailTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SignUpViewController.textFieldDidChange), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
}

func textFieldDidChange() {
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, email.isEmpty, let password = passwordTextField.text,
    password.isEmpty else  {
        signInButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        signInButton.isEnabled = true
        return
    }
    signInButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControl.State.normal)
    signInButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: I reformatted your code a bit. It was missing the final closing brace, which I added as I assume that you meant to have it there. If that is not your intention, you can roll back the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the general Sigabrt Main thread issue case, you can verify duplication event of this control. Sometime, can be caused of this.